# How to get every combination of color, position, number, and overall placement of some dots in an image?

Tags: python, combinations, nested-loops

I am making some code that generates an image of 1-4 dots, with a variety of colors for each dot, varying positions for the dots relative to each other (arranged in a 2x2 grid shape), and different positions relative to the entire image:

Different positions relative to each dot:

[image: Two dots positioned vertically] ...as opposed to...[image: Two dots positioned horizontally]

Different positions relative to the the image: (border to make it easier to see)

[image: Four dots positioned near the top corner of the screen] ...as opposed to... [image: Four dots positioned near the bottom of the screen]

**I want to have my code create every possible combination of these settings, provided no dots overlap** (only 15 possible patterns: 4 possible positions for 1 dot, 6 possible positions for 2 dots, 4 possible positions for 3 dots, and 1 possible position for 4 dots) I have those position combinations stored in a list of sublists (see `posOps` below), where each number represents a position for a dot (1 is top left, 2 is top right, etc.), and the length of each sublist is how many dots there are in that frame.

This is my current code:

```py
colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "black"]
posOps = [[1], [2], [3], [4], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 2, 4], [2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]]

for x in range(3, 20):
    for y in range(3, 20:
        for pos in posOps:
            for dotPos in pos:
                createCircle(screen, x, y, dotPos) #color can be added as an argument on the end
            capture(screen)
```

My issue is, this code does not handle the color of each dot. I need it to have a picture for every position with every combination of colors (multiple dots can have the same color).
I have no idea how to do that.

I cant do something like this because it would just create 7 dots for each position, all of varying colors, stacked on top of each other, and then take a picture. All you would see is black dots.

```py
for x in range(3 * s, 20 * s):
    for y in range(3 * s, 20 * s):
        for pos in posOps:
            for dot in pos:
                for c in colors:
                    createCircle(screen, x, y, dot, c)
            capture(screen)
```

So does anyone have an idea for how I can do the colors portion of this?

P.S. I had no idea what to title this question, if you have an idea for a better title please let me know.

Comment: `from itertools import combinations`

Comment: @TomServo I have tried to use that, but I couldnt make it work, because I still have to get every combination of colours for each dot in each position position, and I wouldnt know how many colours to get and how to ensure I had every combination for that many dots.

Comment: I guess my issue is getting colour combinations to go along with the dot positions. I can get every combination fine, whether with iterables or with loops, but I need combinations that work with only the specific position combinations I have, to prevent overlapping dots and ensure I can take a picture of each overall combination.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import combinations, permutations


positionings = ['topleft', 'topright', 'bottomleft', 'bottomright']
colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple", "black"]
fields = [1, 2, 3, 4]
possibilities = []
for positioning in positionings:
    for num_dots in range(1, len(fields) + 1):
        for dot_positions in list(combinations(fields, num_dots)):
            for dot_colors in list(combinations(colors, num_dots)):
                for color_assignment in list(permutations(dot_colors, num_dots)):
                    possibility = {
                        'position': positioning,
                        'dots': {
                            position: color for position, color in zip(
                                dot_positions, color_assignment
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    possibilities.append(possibility)

print(possibilities[:10])
```

prints

```
[{'position': 'topleft', 'dots': {1: 'red'}},
 {'position': 'topleft', 'dots': {1: 'orange'}},
 {'position': 'topleft', 'dots': {1: 'yellow'}},
 ...
 {'position': 'topleft', 'dots': {1: 'green', 3: 'blue'}},
 {'position': 'topleft', 'dots': {1: 'blue', 3: 'green'}},
 {'position': 'topleft', 'dots': {1: 'green', 3: 'purple'}},
 ...
 {'position': 'topleft', 'dots': {2: 'orange', 3: 'yellow', 4: 'green'}},
 {'position': 'topleft', 'dots': {2: 'orange', 3: 'green', 4: 'yellow'}},
 {'position': 'topleft', 'dots': {2: 'yellow', 3: 'orange', 4: 'green'}}]
```

Gives a total of $4\sum_{i=1}^4{4 \choose i}{7 \choose i}i! = 7840$ possibilities.

Comment: I ended up doing something slightly different to what I asked about, and my method is working now. This seems like a pretty good solution (although I dont think you entirely understood the question - what you have as `fields` is the position of the dots, meaning the `position` key is unneeded here - , which is probably no fault of your own, I did a pretty bad job explaining). Either way, while I appreciate the answer, I no longer need it. Should I mark as correct? Should I delete the question?

Comment: I would say mark it only as an answer if you feel it indeed answers the question, and don't delete it, since someone might stumble upon it at some point in the future and find something useful.